# c# FileStream (FileAccess.Read) block other programs acess on .Close()

Tags: c#, filestream

I have a program that copies video files, while they are being played.

More often than not, the video player (3rd party) is unable to access the file for around half a second (playback freezes) whenever I Close() the FileStream in my program.

From what I can tell, it won't matter if I use Dispose() instead of Close().
The file is copied to the new location as expected, so the playback freeze is the issue I need to solve, but frankly I do not know the specifics on how the 3rd party software reads the file. 
I just can't wrap my head around why the problem appears exactly when I close the reading stream.

I would like to avoid having to postpone the copy process until the video player is done playing.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
FileStream SourceFile = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

while(bytesLeftToCopy > 0)
{
 int _BlockSize = 1024 * 1024;
 byte[] _BlockBuffer = new byte[_BlockSize];

 SourceFileBytes = SourceFile.Read(_BlockBuffer, 0, _BlockSize);
 //you get the idea
}
SourceFile.Close();
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking? You want to open `FileStream` in two programs simultaneously ?

Comment: Is your copy failing or the video playing failing?  Which is called first?  Are you positive that both of these actions do not lock the file from additional read access?

Comment: Sorry ill try to elaborate further

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `File.Copy`?

Comment: Yes the program is designed to throttle the speed of the copy process, so that there are always resources enough for other processes on the machine.

Comment: Out of interest, does using `File.Copy` change the freezing behaviour? Does it make it worse?

Comment: Quite possibly the problem is that closing the file causes a flush and a directory update, all of which take time and could possibly invalidate the readahead cache that the video player is depending on. So the video player reaches the end of its buffer and has to wait for the disk to be available so that it can read the next block of data from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrap your filestream into using construction? It automatically disposes the object after execution.

```
using (FileStream SourceFile = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
//read
}
```

Comment: Does this work differently that using Close() or Dispose()? From what I could find in MSDN that is not the case.

Comment: I have read your post again and now I get it. Have you tried to use contructor with non-default fileshare property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

Comment: This answer lead me to look at other constructors, which in turn led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have bothered you guys, but it turns out that the problem was in the writing part of the program.

The guy who wrote this didn't flush the writing stream, which meant alot of data was cached when the read loop came to an end. Which in turn meant alot of system resources were used at Close() time.

I switched to the constructor (for the write stream) that accepts the FileOptions.WriteThough argument. This seems to have solved the problem.

Thanks for the suggestions you provided... I'll try to be more thorough when I create my next questions.